# Is it possible edit Json Output?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am a newbie php guy. So i need json datas for my ios application. I can get datas from my database and print as json..I wanna send many type datas with json. So  i need edit my json output.
Hereby the json output that i have now:

```
[{"PlaceId":"1","PlaceAdminId":"5","PlaceName":"Alinin Yeri","PlaceAddress":"Be?ikta?","PlaceImage1":"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","PlaceImage2":null,"PlaceImage3":null,"PlaceImage4":null},

{"ActivityId":"1","ActivityName":"zulfu livaneli","ActivityDescription":"Zulfu konseri","ActivityType":"1","ActivityDate":"2011-00-00","PlaceName":"Alinin Yeri","PlaceId":"1"},

{"ActivityId":"2","ActivityName":"Bir tat bir doku","ActivityDescription":"Y?lmaz Erdo?an oyunu","ActivityType":"3","ActivityDate":"2013-00-00","PlaceName":"Alinin Yeri","PlaceId":"1"},
```

And  this is how i want:

```
[Places:{{"PlaceId":"1","PlaceAdminId":"5","PlaceName":"Alinin Yeri","PlaceAddress":"Be?ikta?","PlaceImage1":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFAAAABQCAYAAACOEfKtAAAAHGlET1QAAAACAAAAAAAAACgAAAAoAAAAKAAAACgAAADWVJb57gAAAKJJREFUeAHs1LEJADAMA8Hsv3SyQ6RGcIVLG\/FYf+69x\/wzAC98IAAB\/K9fQ10+0Af6wOkWTIdvOCy9ASAHcuB0C6bDp\/5q7APIgRw43YLp8A2HpTcA5EAOnG7BdPjUX419ADmQA6dbMB2+4bD0BoAcyIHTLZgOn\/qrsQ8gB3LgdAumwzcclt4AkAM5cLoF0+FTfzX2AeRADpxuwXT4hsPSGw8AAP\/\/ttPzCAAAAKBJREFU7dSxCQAwDAPB7L90skOkRnCFSxvxWH\/uvcf8MwAvfCAAAfyvX0NdPtAH+sDpFkyHbzgsvQEgB3LgdAumw6f+auwDyIEcON2C6fANh6U3AORADpxuwXT41F+NfQA5kAOnWzAdvuGw9AaAHMiB0y2YDp\/6q7EPIAdy4HQLpsM3HJbeAJADOXC6BdPhU3819gHkQA6cbsF0+IbD0hsPozm5V7YwxV0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=","PlaceImage2":null,"PlaceImage3":null,"PlaceImage4":null}},

Activities:{{"ActivityId":"1","ActivityName":"zulfu livaneli","ActivityDescription":"Zulfu konseri","ActivityType":"1","ActivityDate":"2011-00-00","PlaceName":"Alinin Yeri","PlaceId":"1"},

{"ActivityId":"2","ActivityName":"Bir tat bir doku","ActivityDescription":"Y?lmaz Erdo?an oyunu","ActivityType":"3","ActivityDate":"2013-00-00","PlaceName":"Alinin Yeri","PlaceId":"1"},

{"ActivityId":"3","ActivityName":null,"ActivityDescription":"Y?l?n son derbisi","ActivityType":"2","ActivityDate":"2012-00-00","PlaceName":"Alinin Yeri","PlaceId":"1"}}]
```

and my php code:

```
$showresult = mysql_query($sqlQuery1);
$showresult1 = mysql_query($sqlQuery2);
$multi_array = array();
$multi_array1 = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($showresult)){
  $multi_array[] = $row;
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($showresult1)){
 $multi_array1[] = $row;
}
$result = array_merge($multi_array1, $multi_array);
print json_encode($result);
```

EDIT
Or is there any method to do what i want?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's possible

Comment: Best sentence that i heard today. Do you know how?

Comment: the process is not called "edit" it may be called "building json the way I need"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break up your code into two parts. One part gets the "Places" rows from the database, and the second gets the "Activties" rows from the database. Then you do something like

```
$php_result=array(
"Places"=> $places_rows,
"Activities"=> $activities_rows 
);

$json_result= json_encode($php_result);
```

Comment: Thats certainly what i want. Thanks Matt. I tested and it works.I think at client side resultDictionary objectForKey:"Places" will give me places as array, right ?